# How to extract a list of string from xml file?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xslt, xpath

I have an xml file and an attribute "name" in some of the tags.
If I give the correct xpath - is there a way to extract a list of strings, each element being one of the values of this attribute?
(I do not need to get the entire list of DOM nodes...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath 2.0 or with XQuery you can write `//@name/string()` to get a sequence of string values of all `name` attributes in the document. With XPath 1.0 you can select the attribute nodes with `//@name` but then you need to use your host language (e.g. Java) to build a list of all the attribute values.